# Add routing prefix globally to Blazor Web Assembly

Tags: routes, blazor, url-routing, blazor-webassembly

I am working on Blazor Web Assembly project that supports multi-language. The requirement was to add the language to the URL as the first segment.

I added the localization and resource files and everything seems to work fine but I have to add the prefix to every route on every page in order for the page to be recognized.

```
@page "/{lang}/counter"

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public string Lang { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way to add the prefix `/{lang}` globally which will be applied to all routes by default and maybe set the value to an injectable service?

Thanks and happy coding

Comment: Till now I couldn't find any solution for this situation. I am not sure if it is anyways possible.

Answer (score 0):

In my project, I also needed to use a language prefix in the first segment of the URL. After a very long search for a solution to simplify the creation of routed components with multi-language support through the first segment in the URL, I came to the only solution - using T4 to generate the Route attribute for routed components.

Below is this T4 file. In which you only need to fill in the input data:

1. An array of languages used in the application. There can be any number of languages.
2. An array with the name of the class of the routed component and routes for it.

After making changes to the input data, it is necessary to regenerate the T4 file to obtain a .cs file with the partial class of routed components and the Route attributes to them.

For convenience, I recommend placing the T4 file in the Pages folder, where all routable components are located.

P.S. For multilingual support in Blazor server through the first URL segment, I advise you to read this article:
https://plbonneville.com/blog/url-based-localization-scheme-for-blazor-server/

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="true" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
<#  // Input data
    /// <summary>List of prefix language segments for all routes</summary>
    string[] languages = new string[] { "ru", "uz", "en" };

    /// <summary>Name for project namespace</summary>
    string nameSpace = "BlazorApp.Pages";

    /// <summary>Data for generating routable components</summary>
    RoutableComponents[] routableComponents = new RoutableComponents[] {
        new RoutableComponents {
            Name = "Index",
            FixedRoutes = new string[] {
                "/"
            },
            Routes = new string[] {
                ""
            }
        },
        new RoutableComponents {
            Name = "Counter",
            FixedRoutes = new string[] {
                "/counter"
            },
            Routes = new string[] {
                "/counter",
                "/counter/{Segment1?}",
                "/counter/{Segment1}/{Segment2?}/{*Segments}",
            }
        },
        new RoutableComponents {
            Name = "FetchData",
            FixedRoutes = new string[] {
                "/fetchdata"
            },
            Routes = new string[] {
                "/fetchdata",
                "/fetchdata/{Segment1?}",
                "/fetchdata/{Segment1}/{Segment2?}/{*Segments}",
            }
        }
    };
#>
<#  // The code generation
    Write("using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;\n\n");
    Write("namespace {0};\n\n", nameSpace);

    foreach(var component in routableComponents) {
        foreach(var route in component.FixedRoutes) {
            Write("[Route(\"{0}\")]\n", route);
        }
        foreach(var route in component.Routes) {
            foreach(var language in languages) {
                Write("[Route(\"/{0}{1}\")]\n", language, route);
            }
        }
        Write("public partial class {0} : ComponentBase {{ }}\n\n", component.Name);
    }
#>

<#+
    public struct RoutableComponents {
        public string Name;
        public string[] FixedRoutes;
        public string[] Routes;
    }
#>
```

The result is the following .cs file:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;

namespace BlazorApp.Pages;

[Route("/")]
[Route("/ru")]
[Route("/uz")]
[Route("/en")]
public partial class Index : ComponentBase { }

[Route("/counter")]
[Route("/ru/counter")]
[Route("/uz/counter")]
[Route("/en/counter")]
[Route("/ru/counter/{Segment1?}")]
[Route("/uz/counter/{Segment1?}")]
[Route("/en/counter/{Segment1?}")]
[Route("/ru/counter/{Segment1}/{Segment2?}/{*Segments}")]
[Route("/uz/counter/{Segment1}/{Segment2?}/{*Segments}")]
[Route("/en/counter/{Segment1}/{Segment2?}/{*Segments}")]
public partial class Counter : ComponentBase { }

[Route("/fetchdata")]
[Route("/ru/fetchdata")]
[Route("/uz/fetchdata")]
[Route("/en/fetchdata")]
[Route("/ru/fetchdata/{Segment1?}")]
[Route("/uz/fetchdata/{Segment1?}")]
[Route("/en/fetchdata/{Segment1?}")]
[Route("/ru/fetchdata/{Segment1}/{Segment2?}/{*Segments}")]
[Route("/uz/fetchdata/{Segment1}/{Segment2?}/{*Segments}")]
[Route("/en/fetchdata/{Segment1}/{Segment2?}/{*Segments}")]
public partial class FetchData : ComponentBase { }
```